# RedirectMatch exclude certain directory

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I'm using `RedirectMatch 301` to redirect requests like mydomain.com/example to an example page. For that I'm using the following code in my .htaccess file:

```
RedirectMatch 301 (?i)/whatever http://thedomain.com
```

The (?i) is so that the redirect is case-insensitive. What I want to achieve now is that that only works when the /whatever is put directly after mydomain.com, so mydomain.com/sub/sub/whatever won't redirect the user.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regex anchors to restrict your match:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^(?i)/whatever/?$ http://thedomain.com
```